# Get NDBI, NDVI, NDWI from Landsat 1

Tags: landsat

I am trying to compare the urban growth of a city from the '80s to 2022, so I need to use Landsat 1 imaginery.
For Landsat 8 the NDBI index is clear but what about for Landsat 1.

Which bands should I use to get this index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the (central and bandwidth of the) wavelengths of the LS8 bands you are using (e.g. here https://eos.com/find-satellite/landsat-8/). Then check which LS1 bands have similar wavelengths. Then apply the same formulas with those bands.